# Remove attribute for body tag angular application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an index.html page which has common template for my entire website, using angular my specified pages will get inserted in the following tag:

```
<data id="mainView"></data>
```

My index.html has an attribute in the body tag as follows:

```
<body myAttribute="teal">
```

I want this 'myAttribute' to be removed when  a specific page (login.html)is to be loaded in the mainView tag.   How do I achieve the same???

Below is the state provider of my application

```
stateProvider.state('login',{
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl : 'login.html',
                controller: 'myController'
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `onEnter` & `onExit` hook of state definition, add and remove attribute from there. If you wanted to do it for single state.

```
stateProvider.state('login',{
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl : 'login.html',
    controller: 'myController',
    onEnter: ['$document', function($document){
       angular.element($document).find('body').removeAttr('myAttribute');
    }],
    onExit: ['$document', function($document){
       angular.element($document).find('body').attr('myAttribute', teal);
    }]
})
```

Comment: . yeah that works when login.html is displayed but when I try to navigate away to some other page still the myattribute is removed

Comment: This answer is nice!